# How to avoid "Press Enter or type command" after execution of a mapped command?

Tags: key-bindings

Following [this Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font_size_quickly#Mapping_solution), I've made two mappings to change font size on scroll wheel:

```
nnoremap <C-ScrollWheelUp> :silent! let &guifont=substitute(&guifont,' \zs\d\+','\=eval(submatch(0)+1)','')<CR>
nnoremap <C-ScrollWheelDown> :silent! let &guifont=substitute(&guifont,' \zs\d\+','\=eval(submatch(0)-1)','')<CR>
```

But despite the `<CR>` at the end, on single Ctrl+Scroll I still get "Press Enter or type command to continue" message, while the command above it is echoed without the `<CR>`.

How can I suppress this message so that multiple successive scrolls just gradually changed the font size without need to press Enter after each scroll event?

If it matters, I'm on Linux with GTK2 GUI for gVim.

Comment: I don't know why the prompt appears in this particular case, but when you want to be sure that a mapping doesn't bother you with a prompt, you can use `:silent!` in the `{rhs}` like you did, and add the argument `<silent>` just after `:nnoremap`. So, it would give something like: `nnoremap <silent> <C-ScrollWheelUp> :silent! let ...`. The difference between `:silent!` and `<silent>` is the following: `:silent!` makes sure the output of the command is not displayed, while `<silent>` makes sure the command itself is not displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a second `<CR>` at the end fixes it for me. I have to admit I'm not sure why you need it, though.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. I'll wait a bit before accepting to allow others to post answers which could explain why the second `<CR>` is needed.

Comment: One potential hint is that the problem does not occur if the value of `guifont` is empty.

Comment: I think I know what happens: the first `<CR>` just finishes entering the command: without it you'll have the command typed in but not activated (you could then interactively edit it). The second one just does what the prompt requests.